# How to save a message body of an email?

Tags: django, html-email, email-attachments, email

how to save the message body, so that it can be used to display any other page!!

I am using Django, HTML

I have a .html page **compose_mail.html**, in which there are fields like:

- TO: (reciever's email address)
- Title
- Message Body (WYSIWYG Editor)
- send button

Now, i have another html page, **mail_details.html** with fields:

- Send To: (Reciever's Email Address)
- Message Body: (WYSIWYG Editor)

I want to save the message body in database or any folder and use that reference to see in my sent mails body in **mail_details.html** page.

if i save this body message as a text in database-table-column than any large size message cannot be saved. as the email message body consists of formatted text, image, url, any type of text font and much more.

Please help me out in this problem statement.

Comment: use django-ckeditor. You can add images, fonts, even youtube video if you want.

Comment: hi @sandeep thanks for your reply.. but how to this editor will help me in saving the message that will be written in this editor to use anywhere whenever required.. like fetching data from the database where ever necessary to display

Comment: Sorry for late reply..this creates a RichTextUploadingField() field. this is same as other fields like Charfield() or IntegerField(). you can save/update/delete/retrieve data in same way. Just check it. you will find it usefull. I am using it in my project and requirements are same as yours.

Comment: @sandeep, Thanks man!! Could you please provide me any sample code or reference link by i'll be abe to use this in my project.. That will be a great help for me!!

Comment: check this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6y6cn1XUfw go through complete video.

Comment: @sandeep ... how to fetch data from database and show on the HTML page on click of a button by using ajax and without reloading the page!!

Comment: can you show your views and template. And if you are begginer in django, check django ORM, writing queries in django, django template. I can write code here but you should know basic concepts.

Comment: @sandeep, i am not using forms, as custom html design. How to use this ckeditor and send and save data in database from here